# $y'(x^2+1)+4x(y+1)^2 = 0, y(1)=1$ interval of validity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

İnformation
$y'(x^2+1)+4x(y+1)^2 = 0, y(1)=1$  solve the initial value problem and find the interval of validity of the
solution.

I am stuck at $1/(y+1)=2\ln(x^2+2)$

Comment: What exactly is $y'(x^2+1)+4x(y+1)^2$ supposed to be equal to?

Comment: I ask because $y'(x^2+1)+4x(y+1)^2$ is an expression, not an equation.

Comment: 0 forgot to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already figured out, a bit of rearranging shows that, if $y\neq-1$, then
$$-\frac{4x}{x^2+1}=\frac{y'}{(y+1)^2}=\left(-\frac{1}{y+1}\right)',$$
and so integrating w.r.t. $x$ then shows that
$$\frac{1}{y+1}=\ln(x^2+1)+C,$$
for some constant $C$. Then rearranging a bit more shows that if $\ln(x^2+1)\neq -C$ we have
$$y=\frac{1}{\ln(x^2+1)+C}-1,$$
and in particular the initial condition then implies that $C=\tfrac12-\ln2$.  So we have
$$y=\frac{1}{\tfrac12-\ln2+\ln(x^2+1)}-1.$$
Of course this function is not defined if and only if the denominator vanishes; this happens when
$$\ln(x^2+1)=\tfrac12-\ln2=\ln(\tfrac12\sqrt{e}),$$
which is impossible because $\tfrac12\sqrt{e}<1\leq x^2+1$.

Comment: Few typos: $$\frac{y'}{(y+1)^2}=\color{red}{-}\big(\frac{1}{y+1}\big)'$$ and $$\int \frac{-4x}{x^2+1}dx=-\color{red}{2}\ln(x^2+1)+c$$

Comment: @Äres Thanks for spotting, everything should be correct now.